# How to replace a value depending on "identifier columns" and an additional condition in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

As part of some data cleaning I need to 'align' the values in a 'Column A' for each 'Year' and 'ID' combination depending if there is any value = 1 in 'Column A' for a 'Year' and 'ID' combination

I already tried `np.where()` but only received `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Here is a short example Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2007, 0], 
                       [2, 2008, 0], 
                       [2, 2009, 1], 
                       [3, 2007, 0], 
                       [4, 2010, 0], 
                       [4, 2011, 1], 
                       [4, 2011, 0]]), #I want to change this 0 to 1
             columns=['ID', 'Year', 'ColA'])
```

the result should look like this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2007, 0], 
                       [2, 2008, 0], 
                       [2, 2009, 1], 
                       [3, 2007, 0], 
                       [4, 2010, 0], 
                       [4, 2011, 1], 
                       [4, 2011, 1]]),
             columns=['ID', 'Year', 'ColA'])
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly do you wanna achieve

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: `df['ColA'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year'])['ColA'].transform(max)`?

Comment: Thanks that gives the desired result :) What is the difference to the solution of Erfan?

Comment: Please review the how-to-ask guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html). Then we get a `boolean` back so if we transform it to `int` with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) we get the desired result:

```
m = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year'])['ColA'].transform(any).astype(int)
df['ColA'] = m
```

```
   ID  Year  ColA
0   1  2007     0
1   2  2008     0
2   2  2009     1
3   3  2007     0
4   4  2010     0
5   4  2011     1
6   4  2011     1
```